# Bokeh- refer to child within a row within a layout

Tags: python, reference, bokeh

How would one refer to `p2` in :

`layout1=layout(row(p1,p2), p3)`

where p1, p2, and p3 are plots?

I've attempted `layout1.children[0][1]` but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Oftentimes, posting a question quickly boosts my research ability, and it is no different here. To refer to p2 in:

`layout1=layout(row(p1,p2), p3)`

it is:

`layout1.children[0].children[1]`

Now I can speak to all my grandchildren!